# Wordpress div class container, is it special in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Hiall,
could someone please tell me, is the

```
<div class="container">
```

class/element some kind of special class for wordpress???

This div is currently wrapping all the content on my site and I am trying to put html code outside of this div, but no matter what I do it won’t let me and it automatically puts everything inside this div.

I’m looking at the file that contains the ending

```
</body>
</html>
```

tags for the document and when I try to put code right before the end like

```
<div class=“myotherrclass”></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I load the page in the browser the last tag before , it  automatically always puts the closing  tag for the container div! eg.

```
<div class=“myotherrclass”></div>
</div> <!— container class closing div, automatically appears from no where! —>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help trying to understand what is happening would be great

Comment: Are you using bootstrap theme?

Comment: You must be using a bootstrap related theme and you need to modify theme to change that class.

Comment: Hi guys, no it's theme I have built from scratch! I don't understand what is going on, I was able to get code to be placed "above" the container div, but still I have a </div> closing tag magically appearing in my footer and I can't get code below it! Just bizarre, I am doing some jQuery stuff but this class is not effected, I'll keep investigating

Answer (score 0):

I started with the Underscores.me starter theme and just deleted the "container" div from both header.php (the opening) and footer.php (the closing). And...nothing bad happened! Will report back if something does, but right now I'm deleting div tags not being used in order to make sense of what's going on. This one's gone!